# Transfer a comma Delimited text file to an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code to transfer a comma Delimited text file before output to an excel sheet with the correct rows and columns as in the text file, but have subscript out of range error on large txt file size on this line `DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)`

```
Sub DelimitedTextFileToArray()


    Dim ColCnt      As Long
    Dim cnt         As Long
    Dim DataIn()    As Byte
    Dim DataOut     As Variant
    Dim Delimiter   As String
    Dim File        As String
    Dim Line        As Variant
    Dim Lines       As Variant
    Dim RngOut      As Range
    Dim RowCnt      As Long
    Dim Text        As String
    Dim Wks         As Worksheet

        ' // Use the ActiveSheet. You specifiy any sheet you want here.
        Set Wks = ActiveSheet

        ' // Starting cell for output.
        Set RngOut = Wks.Range("A1")

        File = "C:\jmp\P428520200530.txt"

        ' // Character that separates the data fields.
        Delimiter = ","

            ' // Read the whole file into memory as byte data.
            Open File For Binary Access Read As #1
                ReDim DataIn(LOF(1))
                Get #1, , DataIn
            Close #1

            ' // Find the rows and the greastest column width needed for the transpose array.
            For n = 0 To UBound(DataIn, 1) - 1
                ' // Is this byte a delimiter?
                If DataIn(n) = Asc(Delimiter) Then cnt = cnt + 1 ' Count the number of columns in this line.

                '// Is this the end of the line?
                If DataIn(n) = 13 Then
                    ' // Save the greatest number of columns found.
                    If cnt > ColCnt Then ColCnt = cnt
                    cnt = 0                 ' Reset the line column count.
                    RowCnt = RowCnt + 1     ' Increase the row count.
                End If
            Next n

            ' // Convert the bytes into a string.
            Text = StrConv(DataIn, vbUnicode)

            ' // Create an array of the lines.
            Lines = Split(Text, vbCrLf)

            ' // Dimension the transpose array.
            ReDim DataOut(ColCnt, RowCnt)

            ' // fill the transpose array.
            For RowCnt = 0 To UBound(DataOut, 2) - 1
                Line = Split(Lines(RowCnt), Delimiter)
                For cnt = 0 To UBound(Line)
                    DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)
                Next cnt
            Next RowCnt

            ' // Output the array to the worksheet.
            RngOut.Resize(ColCnt + 1, RowCnt + 1).Value = DataOut

End Sub
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is check *what are the values of my variables?* when the error occurs, check what the variables represent. Also is this written in `vba` or `vbscript` - they are not the same, please edit your tags appropriately.

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between `ReDim DataOut(ColCnt, RowCnt)` and then `DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the mismatch commented by @BigBen need to changed to ReDim DataOut(RowCnt, ColCnt) and fixed the For loop counter (remove -1) & changed to UBound(DataOut, 1), and changed to Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt+1) to completely output Dataout on the worksheet. Thanks!

```
         ReDim DataOut(RowCnt, ColCnt)

        ' // fill the transpose array.
        For RowCnt = 0 To UBound(DataOut, 1)
            Line = Split(Lines(RowCnt), Delimiter)
            For cnt = 0 To UBound(Line)
                DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)
            Next cnt
        Next RowCnt

        ' // Output the array to the worksheet.
        RngOut.Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt+1).Value = DataOut
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using text to column?